# Как в Android studio сохранять местоположения элементов layout при повороте экрана и сохранять данные

Tags: android-layout, configuration, rotation

Я уже более 5 часов пытался найти решение моей проблемы в интернете, но к сожалению ничего нужного не нашел.
Объясню суть. Есть приложение с двумя формами 1 где есть кнопка старт и веб вью (один объект по разным условиям не видим. 2 содержит в себе механизм игры в колесо фортуны.
Мне нужно сохранять данные формы при повороте экрана. Но когда я пытаюсь это сделать с помощью прописи в манифест строки           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize" у меня элементы начинают улетать в разные стороны и теряются за пределами экрана. Почему это происходит я не знаю. Но это сохраняет состояние формы при повороте экрана.
Другой пример я делал сохранение данных через методы  onSaveInstanceState и  onRestoreInstanceState. они позволяли мне сохранять значение TextView при повороте экрана, но сам объект колесо, которое вращается с анимацией я не знаю как сохранить его состояния т.к метода outState.putImageView не существует.
Я уже пол интернета перерыл чтобы понять от чего это происходит но ничего не нашел. А без правильного расположения элементов и сохранения состояния приложение выглядит некорректно.
Буду очень  признателен если кто сможет мне объяснить суть проблемы и ее решения т.к уже очень устал над этим приложением работать. [image: Экран до поворота с использованием в манифесте orientation|keyboard|screenSize] [image: После поворота] [image: до поворота]
[image: после поворота]

Comment: запрети поворот экрана и всё

Comment: нельзя. Мне четко сказали сделать поворот экрана.